# Puppeteer "Failed to launch the browser process!" when launching multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to launch multiple instances of browser to handle my tasks simultaneously.
To illuminate I used the following code:

```
export async function play() {
    const b1 = await launchBrowserPuppeteer()
    const b2 = await launchBrowserPuppeteer()
    const b3 = await launchBrowserPuppeteer()
}
```

where:

```
export const launchBrowserPuppeteer = async () => {
    const options = {
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: env.chromeUserDataDir,
        executablePath: env.chromeExecutablePath,
    }
    return await puppeteer.launch(options);
}
```

I expected three separate windows getting opened, but what happens is like this:

First a chromium window is opened (b1), next a new tab is opened inside that window (b2), and then an exception is thrown:

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!

TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

```
at onClose (\node_modules\puppeteer\src\node\BrowserRunner.ts:268:9)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (\node_modules\puppeteer\src\node\BrowserRunner.ts:255:61)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:539:35)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

When I `close()` browsers and launch a new one, I get no errors. Is launching multiple browsers generally supported by puppeteer, or I'm using it in a wrong way?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

*I'm on a windows machine and the chromium version is 102.*

Comment: This works OK for me on Windows 10. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @theDavidBarton yes, the error is mitigated when the user data is different.  thanks for the link.